# getting return data from url

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to submit user information to a URL using GET, and then get the errors (if there any) and use them to tell the customer what went wrong. So, currently I have a form that submits this customer info into an iframe (so the page is not redirected and I can see the response from my shopping cart software). when the info is submitted, this is the response I get from the shopping cart server:

```
errorFound=1&responseCode=329&...etc.
```

I need to get this response code, and was wondering what the most simple way would be to do it. Once I get it I can tell the customer what the problem is... Should I use java to read the 
data in the iframe once it loads? or can I use something like Fopen to open the URL and get the return data (can't enable fopen on my server though, but something like it?).

Comment: Use ajax calls instead of opening in a new iframe

Answer (score 0):

Java != javascript

A quick way to do it:

```
$errorcodes = array("329" => "Wrong blabla");

if( isset( $_GET['errorFound'] ) && isset( $_GET['responseCode'] ) ){
    $errorNr = (int) $_GET['responseCode'];
    $error = getErrorFromDB();
   //OR
   //$error = isset( $erorCodes[ $errorNr ] )? $errorcodes[ $errorNr] : false;
    if( $error !== false){
      exit( "<script type='text/javascript'>
             alert( '".htmlspecialchars($error)."' )
        </script>"); 
    }

}

function getError( $code )
{
  $code = (int) $code;
  $db = getYourPdoInstance();
  $q = $db->prepare("SELECT `message` FROM `errorCodes` WHERE `errorCode` = ?");
  $q->execute( array( $code) );
  $return = $q->fetch(2);
  return isset($return['message'])?$return['message']:false;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Much! Sorry meant javascript, same to me since I never use Java :), I'll try it out and let you know, thanks again.